# What does the Aedes packages "aedes-persistence" and "mqemitter" do?

Tags: mqtt, cluster-computing, aedes

I am using the [aedes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aedes) MQTT broker. I read on [this page](https://github.com/moscajs/aedes/blob/main/docs/Examples.md) that to use clustering, you need to [mqemitter](https://www.npmjs.com/mqemitter) and [aedes-persistence](https://www.npmjs.com/aedes-persistence). But I am not sure what those packages do. My guess is that **aedes-persistence** stores messages so that in case of a reboot, undelivered messages will not be lost. I have no clue about the **mqemitter** package.